# SAS PROC SQL extract variable associated with value of second variable

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I'm relatively new to PROC SQL. I've searched SO and other places, but haven't found anything that has addressed my issue.

I'm working with student transfer grade information. Students (more than you might expect) take courses multiple times. I'm trying to extract from a dataset the best grade they earned and the semester in which they earned that best grade. I was able to extract best grade with a min(grade) statement. However, I'm having trouble getting the term. Below is what I have. It returns all terms rather than the term associated with the min grade.

```
proc sql;   
create table MATH_2413_trm as   
select ID as ID, Math_TRNS_2413_Term as Math_TRNS_2413_Term     
from work.Engr2     
group by ID     
having min(Math_TRNS_2413_Best_Grade)   
order by ID;
quit;
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thank you,
Brian

Comment: Do you have to use PROC SQL? PROC SUMMARY with IDMIN, IDMAX does this a lot more efficiently.

Comment: What are the grading values ? Is lowest best ?

Comment: Yes, lowest is best.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1: Use PROC SUMMARY instead.

```
   proc summary data=engr2 noprint;
   id TERM;
   class id;
   var math_trns_2413_term;
   output out=want min=Math_TRNS_2413_Term  minID=minTermID;
   run;
```

Method 2: Use a double PROC SORT, which first sorts so that the highest grade is at the top and then the NODUPKEY option only keeps the first record for each ID.

```
  proc sort data=engr2;
  by id descending math_trns_2413_term;
  run;

  proc sort data=engr2 out=max_grades nodupkey;
  by id;
  run;
```

This assumes your term variable is called 'term'.

Comment: Thank you to both of you. I think the PROC SQL @kiran suggests gets me what I want. I'd done the 'having grade = min(grade)' but there is an additional issue I hadn't mentioned/noticed before. Some students have taken a class multiple times and gotten the same grade. When that happens I still get multiples that I have to deal with in a separate step, I suppose.

I don't think the PROC SUMMARY or SORT will get me the data I need. Looks like it'll return the min value of the term the course was taken, not term assoc. with the minimum (best) grade.

Comment: There's a mistake in the code (that would have been identified in the log, where the minID name should be differnet then it works fine. Otherwise the same name seems to cause an issue because it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

As @Reeza explains it is better to do in proc summary. you were close with sql code just missed to mention grade =min(grade) in having clause.

```
data have;
input id  term grade $ ;
datalines;
113 2 B
113 1 A
113 3 C
111 2 B
111 1 A
111 3 C
112 1 B
112 2 A
112 3 C
;

proc sql;
create table want as 
select * from 
have
group by id
having grade = min(grade);
```